# How to find the exact absolute position of any element on any screen on any device in a Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

For demo purpose, I have an app which has a Container in center of it now, in my container I have a Text "O" and the whole Container is wrapped under the GestureDetector widget and I am using the onVerticalDragDown method to find out the exact position of the text "O". and on tapping of the Text it will print something on terminal. I know I can use Inkwell widget to use the on tap method on Text But what if there will be an image and in the image, I want to make a specific part tappable.
Now the problem is for Android Nexus 5 the positions are different than iPhone X, which is obvious, as you can here
for Android:
[For Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxW81.png)

[For iPhone X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBjlq.png)

Now I hardcoded the position in the launch function to print the "Tapped"
Statement. 
now coming to my question how can I make the Text "O" tappable using the positions of the screen on any device android or ios or any Devices?
this is my code:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
Offset _startPos;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

launch() {
  if ((_startPos.dx >= 180.5 && _startPos.dx < 182.0) &&
      (_startPos.dy >= 335.0 && _startPos.dx < 340.0)) {
    print("Tapped");
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Demo"),
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
            onVerticalDragDown: (details) {
              _startPos = details.globalPosition;
              print(_startPos);
            },
            onTap: () {
              launch();
            },
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
                color: Colors.cyan,
                child: Text(
                  "O",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

My screens:

[iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6lxa.png)

[For Nexus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GENH7.png)